# Java - inner private class only to encapsulate construction for outer class

Tags: java, inner-classes, construction

Is this good practice to have class, that is inner class (not static), which only task is to construct and initiate object of outer class (in her constructor)?
Lifetime of this class would be equal to lifetime of constructor of outer class.

Here is example:

```
OuterClass {
    // (...fields here...)
    private ConstructClass {
        // (...some useful methods and fields here...)
        public ConstructClass(String param1, int param2, ...) {
           // (...construction of OuterClass here...)
        }
    }
    public OuterClass(String param1, int param2, ...) {
        new ConstructClass(param1, param2, ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this something you need? Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Yes, for convenience. `OuterClass` is really simple, only complicated part is constructing. I don't want unnecessary fields and methods in `OuterClass`.

Comment: I don't see the point of this. Either use a builder pattern or a factory pattern. This is a confusing muddle of the two.

Comment: isn't this a job for a factory pattern?

Comment: What can an adding inner class and its constructor do that the outer class couldn't?

Comment: Encapsulate code - fields and methods that are needed only in constructor.
I just can't have method-visible methods that exist in `GNU-C` and functional languages, so I figured out that I could gain it using inner class.

Comment: So why don't you put those in the outer class constructor? Can you put a real example?

Comment: I can't define methods in constructor - that's all matter. I'm trying to imitate coding style that I can use in GNU C and functional languages, where I can define method wherever I want to.

Comment: Just write `private` methods. Those methods are part of the initialization procedure of the outer class, not some inner class.

Comment: I edited comment above - all matter is about placing code in the place that this code belongs. This private methods and fields aren't used after construction, so why they should be there? And they would really occupy 4/5 of class definition :P.

Comment: It sounds like your class tries to do too much if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to me like you tried to rediscover [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) :). You came pretty close to it, hovewer it would be much better if you changed your constructor to set single fields only, not to create the whole object.

Creating builder may cause some decrease in efficiency (additional memory in jvm has to be reserved), but it can largely reduce the amount of different parametrized constructors you have to create - the code is MUCH clearer this way. Modifying your code to fulfill the builder paradigm is worth taking into account, but the final decision is up to you.

Comment: In my opinion, Constructor of `ConstructClass` is too simple for builder.

Comment: Builder? Which way? How does the builder demand jvm memory reserve?

Comment: @Val: Because you need an extra object.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth You are right, you'll need extra 20 bytes (not kilo, not mega, not giga, simple bytes) of extra memory. This is barely affordable with default JVM settings. You are right, you'll need to reserve extra memory.

Comment: @Val: Sure, but that adds up if you're building (say) millions of objects.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth What that adds up? Do you understand that Builder ceases to exist as soon it has finished producing the desired object? What happens to objects which are out of scope and gc-reclaimed? Which millions of objects are you talking about? How can you manifest double standards (if we create million of objects without Buider then we need 1 MB of memory, if we created them with Buider, the same objects occupy 2 MB of memory). These are double standards. Your object size should not depend on the way it was produced.

Comment: @Val: It depends on when the GC decides to kick in.

Comment: @Val Well indeed I didn't express myself clear. I was thinking about reserving space for builder, creating object, later freeing space for builder etc. which can use some amounts of CPU time. Moreover, you have to depend on the garbage collector to run when it has to.

Comment: @Krzysztof Stanisławek If it is too simplefor builder there is no need to use an inner constructing class, too.